# How to display views.py results directly and dynamically on template.html in django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I have a django website project with `exper.html` template and views.py as processing backend.

I want when we enter parameters or input in the textarea and after that press the submit button, then views.py can process those parameters and generate images and display them directly in the `exper.html` template file.

below is the code for expert.html and views.py

exper.html:

```
<div class="container-area text-center">
        <form id="myForm" class="row">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="input_text"></label><br>
                <textarea id="input_text" name="input_text" rows="10" cols="100" placeholder="Write Code Here"
                          required></textarea><br><br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <input type="button" value="Run" onclick="submitForm()">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

<script>
    function submitForm() {
        const form = document.getElementById('myForm');
        const csrfToken = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value;
        const inputText = document.getElementById('input_text').value;

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrfToken);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                displayImages(response.data_input_img, response.qam_mod_img);
            }
        };
        xhr.send('input_text=' + encodeURIComponent(inputText));
    }
</script>
```

views.py

```
def exper(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ParameterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            input_text = form.cleaned_data['input_text']
            subcarrier = 0
            mod_order = 0
            for param in input_text.split():
                if param.startswith('subcarrier='):
                    subcarrier = int(param.split('=')[1])
                elif param.startswith('mod_order='):
                    mod_order = int(param.split('=')[1])

            data_in = generate_input_data(subcarrier, mod_order)

            plt.figure()
            plt.stem(data_in, use_line_collection=True)
            plt.title('Data Input')
            plt.xlabel('Indeks Data')
            plt.ylabel('Nilai Data')
            plt.grid(True)
            plt.savefig('static/files/datainput.png')
            data_input_img_base64 = get_base64_encoded_image('static/files/datainput.png')
            plt.clf()
   
            response_data = {
                'data_input_img': data_input_img_base64,               
            }

            return JsonResponse(response_data)
    else:
        form = ParameterForm()

    return render(request, 'exper.html', {'form': form})

def get_base64_encoded_image(image_path):
    with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8')
        return f"data:image/png;base64,{encoded_string}"
```

in the code above, the image has been successfully saved in `static`. however the image still does not appear.
i have also added this in exper.html

```
  <!-- Display the generated images -->
     {% if data_input_img %}
     <div class="container-area text-center">
         <img src="{{ data_input_img }}" alt="Data Input">
     </div>
     {% endif %}
```

is there any other solution or method? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the template is evaluated server side as part of the page request before being delivered to the browser. Unfortunately, because you are using ajax, the page ishn't reloaded and template isn't re-evaluated, so `{% if data_input_img %}` remains false.

You could handle the situation by having your html code keep an empty div where you now have a conditional one, and give it an id

```
 <div class="container-area text-center" id="for-image">
 </div>
```

And then your displayImages() function (either your existing one or a new one for this purpose) can handle the display of the ajax data.

```
function displayImages(data_input_img, qam_mod_img) {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = data_input_img;
    document.getElementById('for_image').appendChild(img);
    ...
}
```